# Reach out to ediFabric about tag, and cleaning

Tags: discussion

Recently, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083355/edi-edifabric-x12-813-format-sequence-arrangement-issue) came to my attention about why a formatted document, when created with a specific library, was appearing with elements in the wrong order.  The question itself could use a little work, but one of the comments/answers made me take a look at the library host site.

In their [guide](http://edifabric.com/guide/), they have this section:

> How to get help? 
>     Types of questions and where to ask:
>     - ‘How do I ?’ or ‘Why do I have this error ?’ – please post to StackOverflow **using the edi tag**.
>     - ‘I have this error and I’m sure it’s a bug’ or ‘I have an idea\feature request’ – please create a new issue in GitHub.
>     - ‘Why do you’ or ‘When will you’ – please use our internal discussion board.

(bolded emphasis mine)

Now, I don't have a problem with them sending people to us for the type of questions they list - it's the purpose of the site.  What I'm worried about is them using the [edi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edi) tag here, since edi is a (well-defined but) general process not specific to any one library.  Probably, we should have an `ediFabric` tag (like many of the other library-specific tags) that they should list.

Comment: One wonders why, after the question came to your attention and certainly before calling attention to it on Meta, did you not fix the "enter image description here" problem...

Comment: @CodyGray - err, I started, but got distracted by the shiny and ran out of time before Labor-Day activities.